# Node smartcard throw SCardConnect error while scanning the card and SCardListReaders error after disconnect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, electron, smartcard

I am also using angular and electron, but everything worked fine previously. This is the error:

```
Error: SCardConnect error: 
SCardConnect error: The smart card cannot be accessed because of other connections outstanding.
(0x8010000b)
```

After the first time scanning a card, it no longer throws error and works fine reading cards until relaunch. Here are some snippets of my code relevant to smartcard:

```
const smartcard = require('smartcard');
const Devices = smartcard.Devices;
const devices = new Devices();
let currentDevices = [];

//something else

app.run(function($rootScope) {
let registerDevices = function (event) {
    currentDevices = event.devices;
    currentDevices.forEach(function (device) {
        device.on('card-inserted', event => {
            let card = event.card;
            console.log(`Card '${card.getAtr()}' inserted into '${card.device}'`);
            $rootScope.$broadcast('card-attach',card.getAtr());
        });
        device.on('card-removed', event => {
        });
        device.on('error', event => {
            console.error("Card Reader Error: " + event);
        });
    });
};

devices.on('device-activated', event => {
    console.log("Reader added :" + event.device);
    registerDevices(event);
});

devices.on('device-deactivated', event => {
    console.log("Reader removed :" + event.device);
    registerDevices(event);
});
});
```

In addition, when I disconnect the scanner, it says

```
events.js:160 Uncaught Error: SCardListReaders error: The Smart Card Resource Manager is not running.
(0x8010001d)

events.js:163 Uncaught Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. ([object Object])
```

And the scanner is not working after reconnect.

Answer (score 1):

This error code is [E_SHARING_VIOLATION](https://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/api/group__ErrorCodes.html#ga81cd3fc9e7e84c66be2471294152235f) -- some process has already connected to the card in exclusive mode (using [SCARD_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE](https://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/api/pcsclite_8h.html#aedc5ddb6c12dd0e9f522d4c669ca9135) for [SCardConnect](https://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/api/group__API.html#ga4e515829752e0a8dbc4d630696a8d6a5)).

---

[Assuming you are under Windows]:

There is a [Plug&Play](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn631754) mechanism in Windows which by default automatically accesses every card immediately after insertion and tries to determine the correct driver for it -- which creates a short time window when the card is being accessed (this is IMHO the most probable cause).

You have two choices:

1. **Deal with it** -- retry the card connection attempt after some time (tens of ms, YMMV) for this particular error code (possibly could be done in loop with some max retry count).
2. **Disable this behavior** -- there are two ways (I have never used the Group Policy one, but it should work):

   a/ using Local Group Policy Settings (disable Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Smart Card -> Turn On Smart Card Plug and Play Service) (see e.g. [here](http://chris-evans-dev.blogspot.cz/2011/03/smartcard-pcsc-scardconnect-sharing.html))

   b/ by setting the registry key `EnableScPnP` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\ScPnP` to `dword:0x00000000` (for a 64-bit system set it under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\ScPnP` as well) -- see e.g. [here](http://www.ugochirico.com/post/2010/10/22/Disable-the-Smart-Card-Plug-Play-Option-in-Windows-7.aspx). Be sure to reboot your system for the change to take effect

---

Regarding your edit with the 0x8010001D ([E_NO_SERVICE](https://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/api/group__ErrorCodes.html#gad4729ab109ff490285d2ad881c04bee8)) error code and reconnecting a reader -- I have no idea.

Good luck!

Comment: I changed the registry and restarted, and it worked for the first time. However, after I relaunched the app the same error occurred again...